# Need setting up blank project with Framework7 v8 (React UI Framework) & NextJS v13

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

There's a guide on Framework7 website: [Next.js & Server-Side Rendering](https://blog.framework7.io/framework7-next-js-server-side-rendering-yes) but it only works for Framework7 v6 and NextJS v10.

I’m trying to follow the same steps as in this guide but for Framework7 v8 & NextJS v13 without luck.

Here’s public repository with my attempt:

https://github.com/olegdater/f7-v8-next-app

Per original guide i followed these steps:

1. ****Create Next.js Project:**** `npx create-next-app f7-v8-next-app` (I used TypeScript setup)
2. ****Install Framework7:**** `npm i framework7 framework7-react framework7-icons material-icons`
3. Setup env files
4. Create `routes.ts` file in `./src/app` dir
5. Create files / pages structure in `./src/app/pages` dir
6. Now I guess I need to hack into `./src/page.tsx` , followed step through "**index.js**" up to the “**Launch**”
7. From here I'm stuck with errors:

   > Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
   >
   > Check your code at page.tsx:58.
   > at MyApp (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./src/app/page.tsx:32:18)

[GitHub commit](https://github.com/olegdater/f7-v8-next-app/commit/f354610d421fa9a9823c8bd7a3aa326e0f7510da)